# Where to put Unix sockets?

Tags: bash, unix, debian, sockets

I am new to this, so sorry if its obvious. I am running a Debian server and installing the likes of UWSGI, Nginx etc on there. The configurations keep talking about pointing to "sockets".

In the build options I seem to be able to specify where the sockets for each program go. By default it looks like most of them go in `/tmp/` (not all of them).

Is this a good place for them to go? I'm trying to keep things as organised as possible but just bunging them in my tmp directory doesn't seem like the best option.

Comment: related: [Idiomatic location for file based sockets on Debian systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88083/366064) on Unix & Linux StackExchange

Answer (score 6):

They are to be stored in `/run/` according to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html).

> System programs that maintain transient UNIX-domain sockets must place them in this directory or an appropriate subdirectory as outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

The defaults I find are usually good. Unix sockets only live while the program is running, so `/tmp/` is usually an alright place for them to live, some programs chose to put them into `/var/run/` (since while they are in essence "temporary", they have persistent names).

Most clients will look for sockets in the default place first, so changing the default socket location may require additional configuration in clients trying to use that service.